# Longitudinal Dataset with 24 time points and a lot of missingness

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, missing-data, glmm

This is my first question, so bear with me (and feel free to edit my code or ask for additional info). I am working with a longitudinal dataset compiled from surveys of veterans using opioids. Data were collected from 230 participants at baseline and in 24 monthly followups. There is, as expected, a lot of missing data. However, due to the nature of the data collection, it is possible for someone to leave the study for two or three waves and come back for a later wave. Accordingly, I have included a table of **how many followups the 230 participants completed out of a possible 24**, instead of a table of how many individuals were present at a given wave:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
36 33 19  6  9  4  6  5  4  7  7  7  2  6  7 11  7  3 11  9  6 11  7  6  1
```

As you can see, 194/230 participants completed at least 1 followup, and 161/230 completed at least 2 followups (making for at least three time points of data).

My goal is to understand how my DV changes over time. A zero-inflated negative binomial distribution is most appropriate for the distribution of the DV. I'm planning to do a generalized linear mixed model with zeroinflated negative binomial regression (After some snooping around this site, I think that might be possible from glmmADB).

**My questions are these:**

1. Is there a more appropriate way to model the change over time in these circumstances? GEE or latent growth curves, perhaps?
2. At what point is the missingness too much of a problem? Should I be subsetting the data to only those with at least three timepoints?
3. What diagnostics should I be running on such a model? I've checked the residuals, but I'm not sure how they should look when the distribution is zero-inflated negative binomial.

Comment: If you are concerned that people with many observations are different from those with few then you could consider adding a categorical moderator with values from 2 to 24 and seeing if it interacts with variables you are interested in. You might need to make it a coarse classification.

Comment: Hi @mdewey. Thanks for the comment.  When you say a coarse classification, do you mean break the time variable or the DV up?  
Comparing ORBS score across the two groups is key. Unless you mean make a categorical variable representing multiple groups (those with more than 2 follow ups, those with more than 6, those with more than four)?

Comment: Your parenthesis is what I meant.